# What class to use for money representation?

Tags: python, currency, rounding-error, arbitrary-precision, precision

What class should I use for representation of money to avoid most rounding errors?

Should I use `Decimal`, or a simple built-in `number`?

Is there any existing `Money` class with support for currency conversion that I could use?

Any pitfalls that I should avoid?

Comment: I always thought that currency conversion is just multiplication.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Yes and no. You have to keep in mind *how* are you going to use the values that you have. How do you do when you payed U$S2000 + AR$6300 + €1500 last year and this year you payed U$S4000 + AR$1200 + €500? There are many things that you have to take into account, so a `Money` object would need to save the historical value *and* current value.

Comment: Pitfall to avoid: using floating point numbers. See Office Space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/python-money/
"Primitives for working with money and currencies in Python" - the title is self explanatory :)

Comment: Looking at http://code.google.com/p/python-money/source/browse/trunk/money/Money.py I can see that they do use `Decimal` for internal representation :)

Answer (score 42):

Never use a floating point number to represent money. Floating numbers do not represent numbers in decimal notation accurately. You would end with a nightmare of compound rounding errors, and unable to reliably convert between currencies. See [Martin Fowler's short essay on the subject](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html).

If you decide to write your own class, I recommend basing it on the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) data type.

I don't think python-money is a good option, because it wasn't maintained for quite some time and its source code has some strange and useless code, and exchanging currencies is simply broken.

Try [py-moneyed](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-moneyed). It's an improvement over python-money.

Comment: decimal is based on a floating point, I'm curious how it fixes the problem

Comment: How it fixes or works around floating point problems is described in the first section of the Python docs for decimal: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: @xenoterracide I think you are confusing "floating point model" with IEEE 754 floating point.  The principle of a floating point model isn't broken, but using hardware based IEEE 754 (binary floating point) for decimal currency calculation is broken.

Answer (score 20):

Just use [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Comment: decimal isn’t suitable because of the way it handles precision. Suppose you’re handling amounts less than $10 bn with a precision of $0.01, so you tell the decimal library your numbers will be no more than 12 digits long. Now you have two problems: your code can’t handle hyper-inflation; and $0.01 will be displayed as '0.010000000000'.

Comment: @Pitarou Forgive my ignorance, but why would you ever reduce the precision, especially in an app that might encounter hyper-inflation? And how do you get that output for `$0.01`? I tried `decimal.getcontext().prec = 12; print(decimal.Decimal('0.01'))` but it prints `0.01` with no trailing zeros. Even if you did get that output, why wouldn't you round it before display?

Answer (score 6):

You could have a look at this library: [python-money](http://code.google.com/p/python-money/). Since I've no experience with it I cannot comment on its usefullness.

A 'trick' you could employ to handle currency as integers:

- Multiply by 100 / Divide by 100 (e.g. $100,25 -> 10025) to have a representation in 'cents'

Comment: Many accounting systems track things far more precisely than to the cent.

Comment: True, but all depends on the needs I guess... The quantlib library referenced in this thread seems a good candidate for 'serious' financial work.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) for working with finance.

It has built in classes for handling currency types and claims 4 years of active development.

Comment: This project looks interesting, but may be a bit too much, I will most likely use a pure python project for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

Simple, light-weight, yet extensible idea:

```
class Money():

    def __init__(self, value):
        # internally use Decimal or cents as long
        self._cents = long(0)
        # Now parse 'value' as needed e.g. locale-specific user-entered string, cents, Money, etc.
        # Decimal helps in conversion

    def as_my_app_specific_protocol(self):
        # some application-specific representation

    def __str__(self):
        # user-friendly form, locale specific if needed

    # rich comparison and basic arithmetics
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._cents < Money(other)._cents
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Money(self._cents + Money(other)._cents)
```

You can:

- Implement only what you need in your application.
- Extend it as you grow.
- Change internal representation and implementation as needed.