# How to convert currency column with $ and , to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string

I have the following data in pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'state': ['California', 'New York', 'Florida', 'Texas'],
        '1st': ['$11,593,820', '$10,861,680', '$7,942,848', '$7,536,817'],
        '2nd': ['$109,264,246', '$45,336,041', '$69,369,589', '$61,830,712'],
        '3rd': ['$8,496,273', '$6,317,300', '$4,697,244', '$5,736,941']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        state          1st           2nd         3rd
0  California  $11,593,820  $109,264,246  $8,496,273
1    New York  $10,861,680   $45,336,041  $6,317,300
2     Florida   $7,942,848   $69,369,589  $4,697,244
3       Texas   $7,536,817   $61,830,712  $5,736,941
```

I want to perform some simple analysis (e.g., sum, groupby) with three columns (1st, 2nd, 3rd), but the data type of those three columns is object (or string).

So I used the following code for data conversion:

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

But, conversion does not work, perhaps, due to the dollar sign. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534746/importing-financial-data-into-python-pandas-using-read-csv

Comment: For a regex solution, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/31521773/3651127

Answer (score 105, accepted):

- pandas has three `.replace` methods:

  1. [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for a column
  2. [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for a column
  3. [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for multiple columns, and removes the need to use `.apply`

  - `regex=False` is the default setting, so set `regex=True`
- `df[df.columns[1:]]` selects the last three columns.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.1.0`**

```py
# replace values only in selected columns
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

# replace values in all columns
df = df.replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

- Additional patterns for cleaning monetary columns:

  - `'[^.0-9]'`: remove all non-digits except decimals points
  - `'[^.0-9\-]'`: remove all non-digits except decimals points, and negative signs
  - `'\D'`: remove all non-digits, including the decimal point, and negative sign, so it's good for positive int only columns

Answer (score 8):

You can use the vectorised `str` methods to replace the unwanted characters and then cast the type to int:

```
In [81]:
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('$','')).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','')).astype(np.int64)
df

Out[81]:
            state       1st        2nd      3rd
index                                          
0      California  11593820  109264246  8496273
1        New York  10861680   45336041  6317300
2         Florida   7942848   69369589  4697244
3           Texas   7536817   61830712  5736941
```

`dtype` change is now confirmed:

```
In [82]:

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
state    4 non-null object
1st      4 non-null int64
2nd      4 non-null int64
3rd      4 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Another way:

```
In [108]:

df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.str[1:].str.split(',').str.join('')).astype(np.int64)
df
Out[108]:
            state       1st        2nd      3rd
index                                          
0      California  11593820  109264246  8496273
1        New York  10861680   45336041  6317300
2         Florida   7942848   69369589  4697244
3           Texas   7536817   61830712  5736941
```

Answer (score 8):

To convert into integer, use:

```
carSales["Price"] = carSales["Price"].replace("[$,]", "", regex=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `locale` as follows

```
import locale
import pandas as pd
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')
df['1st']=df.1st.map(lambda x: locale.atof(x.strip('$')))
```

Note the above code was tested in Python 3 and Windows environment

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method[`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and the regex `'\D'` to remove all nondigit characters or `'[^-.0-9]'` to keep minus signs, decimal points and digits:

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].str.replace('[^-.0-9]', ''))
```

Comment: Use `'[^.0-9\-]'` to keep your negative numbers, otherwise the '-' gets stripped out.

Answer (score -3):

```
df['1st'] = df['1st'].str.replace('$', '').str.replace(',', '').str.split('.', expand=True)[0].astype(int)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, stacking `.str.replace` does work (this answer works), but this is not a good implementation compared to other answers. `.str.split('.', expand=True)[0]` is janky.