# I have a list, in which one of column data has to formatted in such a way that $ sign and Comma should be removed

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

```
data = Index(['borough', 'neighborhood', 'building_class_category',
       'tax_class_at_present', 'block', 'lot', 'ease_ment',
       'building_class_at_present', 'address', 'apart_ment_number', 'zip_code',
       'residential_units', 'commercial_units', 'total_units',
       'land_square_feet', 'gross_square_feet', 'year_built',
       'tax_class_at_time_of_sale', 'building_class_at_time_of_sale',
       'sale_price', 'sale_date'],
      dtype='object')
```

Convert the field “sale_price” to numeric (it is currently formatted as currency which cannot be
used in calculations.) (Hint, you will need to remove the commas and dollar signs.

I tried

```
df=data
df['sale_price']=df['sale_price'].replace('$','')
using 

df['sale_price'] = df['sale_price'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').astype(int)
```

Comment: What is the issue? post some sample data?

Comment: Sale _price is the column with $3,343 etc etc etc.... Need to remove the comma and $

Comment: believe you need to add quotes here: .astype('float64'). If you're getting a specific error message that would be nice to have.

Comment: tried did not work

Comment: IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-85c6c4a0294a> in <module>
      1 df=brooklyn_sales.columns
----> 2 df['sale_price']=df['sale_price'].replace('$','')
      3 df

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   4278         if is_scalar(key):
   4279             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key)
-> 4280             return getitem(key)
   4281 
   4282         if isinstance(key, slice):
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Hmmm something is either off about your df or it's because you need to cast as a float not int

Comment: **Please share a [mcve].**

Comment: @born_naked It’s something off about the df, although not in the way you might think! Indeed, the issue appears to be with the `df` variable, not the actual DataFrame. I know it’s difficult to read, but look at the error message: It looks like OP is defining `df = brooklyn_sales.columns`.

Comment: I have assigned the brooklyn_sales.columns to df, but still                 
   df['sale_price'] = df['sale_price'].str.replace(r'[$,]','').astype(int)                                       even if i use the brooklyn_sales.columns im getting the same error

Comment: @MohanBabu when you set df=brooklyn_sales.columns you are redefining the df to be just the column headers of brooklyn_sales and nothing else. If you want the df to have the same content as brooklyn_sales you should use df=brooklyn_sales. You don't seem to be posting all your code, and it looks like your error messages are result of intermediary steps. You should post all your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, this answer should help:

[converting currency with $ to numbers in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464280/converting-currency-with-to-numbers-in-python-pandas)

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-ede98ed6b522> in <module>
      1 df=brooklyn_sales.columns
----> 2 df[df.sale_price[1:]] = df[df.sale_price[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('$','')).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','')).astype(np.int64)
      3 df

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'sale_price'

Comment: @MohanBabu the error says that it has no column "sale_price". Check again. There could be some spelling mistake.

Comment: when i try to print whole list it displays. There is sale_price column

Comment: Something like this? df[df.columns['sale_price'].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one, replace `int` with any type you need:

```
df['sale_price'] = df['sale_price'].str.replace(r'[$,]','').astype(int)
```

Or this also works:

```
df['sale_price'] = pd.to_numeric(df.sale_price)
```

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-7fa2506a166b> in <module>
      1 df=brooklyn_sales.columns
----> 2 df['sale_price'] = pd.to_numeric(df.sale_price)
      3 

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'sale_price'

Comment: I tested this with my own data and it works. Your error shows that your Dataframe has no column `sale_price`. Can you check it again.