# Pandas how to convert an array of strings ($0.00 format) into decimals

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column in my code which is currently in a string $ format to numeric.

My code is currently:

```
s=top_performing_schools["Per Student Budget"]

top_performing_schools["Per Student Budget"]=pd.to_numeric(s)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "$582.00" at position 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting currency with $ to numbers in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464280/converting-currency-with-to-numbers-in-python-pandas)

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the `$` symbol and then apply the numeric conversion, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Per Student Budget": ["$582.00", "$100", "$12000"]}
)

df["Per Student Budget"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Per Student Budget"].str.replace('$', ''))
print(df)

   Per Student Budget
0               582.0
1               100.0
2             12000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{"Per Student Budget": ["$582.00", "$100", "$12000"]}
)

df["Per Student Budget"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Per Student Budget"].str.replace('$', ''))
print(df)

Per Student Budget
0               582.0
1               100.0
2             12000.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).