# (Matplotlib) Placing custom values on y axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Trying to have my y axis range from 0-450,000 with an increment value of 50000. I believe I have the right technique incorporated with "plt.yticks(np.arange(0,450001,50000))" Confused as to why all my y axis values disappear however when I run it. I have also tried 
    "ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_ylim([0,450000])"
The numbers just end up looking smudged on the bottom of y axis. Here is my code thus far...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ObiP1/The-Future-Value-of-Homes/master/AverageHomeValues.csv')

plt.title('Median Cost Of Maryland Homes', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Median Price Of Home',fontsize=25)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0,450001,50000))

plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=25)
plt.plot(df.YEAR, df.MED_COST)
plt.grid(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your MED_COST column are strings, not numbers. These strings get used as ticklabels, but for tick positions at `0,1,2,3,4,5,...` Setting tick positions at `0, 50000, ...` will make everything invisible, except tick 0.

So, converting these strings to numbers should solve the issues. They can be shown as currencies via the [`StrMethodFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter). Instead of setting the ticks explicitly, [`MultipleLocator(50000)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) is another option to prevent that the ticks should be recalculated when new data comes available.

As `plot` can change some of the settings, first calling `plot` and only afterwards setting labels and ticks can be helpful.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20, 10

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'YEAR': [1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020],
    'MED_COST': ['$31500', '$48700', '$58600', '$71800', '$115400', '$148800', '$146000', '$250242', '$295000']})
# make the 'MED_COST' column numeric
df.MED_COST = [int(m[1:]) for m in df.MED_COST]

plt.plot(df.YEAR, df.MED_COST)
plt.title('Median Cost Of Maryland Homes', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Median Price Of Home', fontsize=25)

plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=25)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 450001, 50000))
# plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(50000))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('${x:,.0f}'))

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Our answers started out approximately the same, I think, but with your edits, this is better (eg, StrMethodFormatter, etc).

Comment: @ObiP1 Was this answer helpful?

Comment: @ObiP1: since you are new here, I'll point out that it would be helpful if you would accept this answer. [This post explains how and why.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) If you have a reason not to, that's fine too, but at this point, it would be useful to explain why, since it seems to be a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$` strings are not interpreted as values but as strings (that line looked much to straight, didn't it?).  If you convert it ([as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464280/converting-currency-with-to-numbers-in-python-pandas)) you get this:

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ObiP1/The-Future-Value-of-Homes/master/AverageHomeValues.csv')
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

plt.title('Median Cost Of Maryland Homes', fontsize=30)
plt.ylabel('Median Price Of Home',fontsize=25)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0,450001,50000))

plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=25)
plt.plot(df.YEAR, df.MED_COST, 'o')
plt.grid(True)
```