# Convert a column of currency strings into floats

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a data frame with the following left side format. I reckon that because of the `,` and the `$` symbol the column has a `string` format, but I want to convert it into float, in order to manipulate the data.

I have used the two following lines of code to strip those characters, hoping it would convert the column values into floats.

```py
sales_dataset_date['invoice_value2'] = sales_dataset_date['invoice_value'].replace('$', '')
sales_dataset_date['invoice_value2'] = sales_dataset_date['invoice_value'].replace(',', '')
```

After I run the above commands, I get the following output:

```
|invoice_value |invoice_value2 |
| $55.87       | $55.87        |
| $28,852.37   | $28,852.37    |
| $1,392.00    | $1,392.00     |
```

I can't convert it into float. There is no difference with the `replace` command. What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting currency with $ to numbers in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464280/converting-currency-with-to-numbers-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Anyway, the answer you are looking for is `sales_dataset_date['invoice_value2'] = sales_dataset_date['invoice_value'].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)`.

Comment: Thak you very much. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['invoice_value2']=df['invoice_value2'].replace('[\$,]','', regex=True).astype(float)
```