# Issue with Pandas. Can't multiply two columns different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been to trying to combine two columns into 1. Quantity and price multiplied together to result in sales. But when i get the sales, it doesn't show the total. It only shows the price reapeated many times. The price type is object and quantity is int. Even when i try to convert price astype(int) it shows an error, I guess because it has $ sign in it and cannot covert it to int.
How can i can I multiply the two columns to get the "price" to show total only in $
Thank you
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIrvo.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUTLa.png)

Tried to changed type and I cannot.

Comment: You can't multiply strings by numbers and get a numeric result. You need to remove the dollar sign and covert to a number. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464280/how-to-convert-currency-column-with-and-to-numbers Also, don't post photos of code — put the code in the question like every other question you see here. Photos are not accessible to everyone, and forces anyone who wants to help to type your code.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's likely the dollar sign. Here's a quick fix:

```
import pandas as pd

# Fake dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "quantity": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "price": ["$5.00", "$4.00", "$3.00", "$2.00", "$1.00"]
})

# Replace "$" with nothing (empty string), then convert to float
df["price"] = df["price"].str.replace("$", "").astype(float)

# Then you can multiply ints with floats
df["total"] = df["quantity"] * df["price"]
```

For future questions, I suggest glancing through this link (you'll likely get better and quicker responses):
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Good luck!