# Matplotlib fix axis - too many dates

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have big data as csv file which has too many dates, so when I plot it, x axis writes all of them, like f.e : from `2000-12-24` to `2017-12-24` and also y axis.

I have tried to use a set, but that set needs to sort and problem is that when I sort it the data from Y isn't for any of sorted dates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib as u
import numpy as np
import csv

stock_price_url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'

date = []
openp = []
high = []
low = []
close = []
adjclose = []
volume = []

text = u.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
with open('nw.csv', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(text)
    fw.close()

with open('nw.csv', 'r') as csvf:
f = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',')
for row in f:
    if 'Date' not in row:
        date.append(row[0])
        openp.append(row[1])
        high.append(row[2])
        low.append(row[3])
        close.append(row[4])
        adjclose.append(row[5])
        volume.append(row[6])

dateset = set([])            
for z in date:
   dateset.add(z[:4])

highset = []
for z in high:
    highset.append(z[:3])


plt.plot(set(dateset), set(highset), linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I think [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) might help you with your problems. See for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27534746/2454357), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38884466/2454357) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17812978/2454357) post for more information.

Answer (score 17):

You need to convert the dates first into a Python `datetime` object. This can then be converted into a matplotlib number. With this you can then tell matplotlib to add ticks based on year or month changes:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib as u
import numpy as np
import csv

stock_price_url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'

date = []
high = []

text = u.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

with open('nw.csv', 'w') as f_nw:
    f_nw.write(text)

with open('nw.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_nw:
    csv_nw = csv.reader(f_nw)
    header = next(csv_nw)

    for row in csv_nw:
        date.append(matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d')))
        high.append(row[2])

ax = plt.gca()
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator([1, 7]))
#ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
#ax.tick_params(pad=20)

plt.plot(date, high, linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

This would give you just the years:
[image: year locators]

Or if you uncomment the minor locator/formatter you would get:
[image: year and month locators]

Note:

1. You do not need to close a file if you are opening it with a `with` block.
2. The script assumes you are using Python 3.x.
3. To skip the header just read it in using `next()` before iterating over the rows in your for loop.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to accept the answer as the accepted solution.