# How to plot large dataset of date vs time using matplot lib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, time

I want to plot date vs time graph using matplot lib. The issue I am facing is that due to access of data many lines are showing on the xaxis and I can't find a way to plot my time on xaxis cleanly with one hour gap. Say i have data in my list as string as ['6:01','6:30','7:20','7:25']. I want to divide my xaxis from 6:00 to 7:00 and the time points between them should be plotted based on time.

Note: time list is just and example I want to do this for whole 24 hour.

I tried to use ticks and many other options to complete my task but unfortunatly I am stuck at this problem. My data is in csv file.

Below is my code:
def arrivalGraph():

```
from datetime import  datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates

with open("Timetable2021.csv","r") as f:

    fileData  = f.readlines()
    del fileData[0]
    date = []
    train1 = []
   
    for data in fileData:
        ind = data.split(",")
        date.append(datetime.strptime(ind[0],"%d/%m/%Y").date())
        train1Time = datetime.strptime(ind[1],"%H:%M").time()
        train1.append(train1Time.strftime("%H:%M"))


    plt.style.use("seaborn")
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
    plt.plot_date(train1,date)

    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()#gcf is get current figure - autofmt is auto format


    dateformater = mpl_dates.DateFormatter("%b ,%d %Y")
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateformater) # to format the xaxis


    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Time")
    plt.title("Train Time vs Date Schedule")
   
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

When i run the code i get the following output:

[output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujXbP.png)

Comment: This question comes up about twice a week.  Suggest mark as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090043/matplotlib-fix-axis-too-many-dates

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every single minute that every single minute is present in `train1` (i.e. `train1 = ["00:00", "00:01", "00:02", "00:03", ... , "23:59"])`, you can use `plt.xticks()` by generating an array representing `xticks` with empty string on every minute which is not 0.

```
    unique_times = sorted(set(train1))
    xticks = ['' if time[-2:]!='00' else time for time in unique_times]

    plt.style.use("seaborn")
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
    plt.plot_date(train1,date)

    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()#gcf is get current figure - autofmt is auto format


    dateformater = mpl_dates.DateFormatter("%b ,%d %Y")
    # I think you wanted to format the yaxis instead of xaxis
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(dateformater) # to format the yaxis


    plt.ylabel("Date")
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.title("Train Time vs Date Schedule")

    plt.xticks(range(len(xticks)), xticks)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

If every single minute is not in the `train1` array, you have to keep `train1` data as an object and generate arrays representing `xticks` location and values to be used as `plt.xticks()` parameters.

```
    date = []
    train1 = []

    for data in fileData:
        ind = data.split(",")
        date.append(datetime.strptime(ind[0],"%d/%m/%Y").date())
        train1Time = datetime.strptime(ind[1],"%H:%M")
        train1.append(train1Time)

    plt.style.use("seaborn")
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
    plt.plot_date(train1,date)

    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()#gcf is get current figure - autofmt is auto format


    dateformater = mpl_dates.DateFormatter("%b ,%d %Y")
    # I think you wanted to format the y axis instead of xaxis
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(dateformater) # to format the yaxis

    plt.ylabel("Date")
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.title("Train Time vs Date Schedule")

    ax = plt.gca()
    xticks_val = []
    xticks_loc = []
    distance = (ax.get_xticks()[-1] - ax.get_xticks()[0]) / 24

    def to_hour_str(x):
        x = str(x)
        if len(x) < 2:
            x = '0' + x
        return x + ':00'

    for h in range(25):
        xticks_val.append(to_hour_str(h))
        xticks_loc.append(ax.get_xticks()[0] + h * distance)

    plt.xticks(xticks_loc, xticks_val, rotation=90, ha='left')


    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Here's the code output using dummy data I generated myself.[image]