# Why Is 'user_input' Always A String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
def user_input_checker(user_input):

  if isinstance(user_input, int):
      print('user_input is an integer.')

  if isinstance(user_input, float):
      print('user_input is a float point.')

  if isinstance(user_input, str):
      print('user_input is a string')

print('What is your input?')
user_input = input()

print('Input = %s'%user_input)

user_input_checker(user_input)
```

I had created some code to check if a user's input was an integer, a float point, or a string, and everytime I would put use an integer or a float point, it would still output that it was a string.
Is there something really easy that I'm missing?

Comment: What language is this? I assume it's Python? If so, please update your question and add the appropriate tags. Also you should clarify if this is Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: `pay_rate` does not appear anywhere in your posted code. **Please post your actual code**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `user_input` is always a `string` because the `input()` function always returns `string` values. [This is described in Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (emphasis mine):

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
>
> The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, `EOFError` is raised.

It's true that Python does not have statically declared types and Python has some type-juggling, but Python variables still have types that *generally* aren't "magic" and so if someone enters `1.2` into an `input()` prompt, it will still be returned as a string `"1.2"` and not a `decimal` value.

Your question title says `pay_rate`, which sounds like a monetary value. [**You must not represent monetary amounts (i.e. currency, money) with a floating-point type** such as `float`. Instead use `Decimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406737/what-class-to-use-for-money-representation).